# Dynamic Services URL Property

Tags: url, settings, smart-device, genexus

I was given a new requirement for the App:
Each client must host its own services, meaning the "Service URL" cannot be fixed.

I got scared but just found the **Dynamic Services URL** property, which is great, and does what I want, but...

Is it possible to change the "Preferences" and "User Information" descriptions (that GX automatically creates)? The App is in Portuguese.

Or, alternatively, can I build my own validation (the check if the URL is set on my startup object)?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to translate those messages as any message on the KB.
First enable static or runtime translation on the KB.
Secondly go to: Folder View > Customization > Localization and filter the messages.
There should appear all the messages shown and you can add your Portuguese translations under the Portuguese language.

Example:
In an example KB you can see this messages:
[image: Image of GXM_Preference message]
and
[image: Multiple Images with more related messages]

For the second part of your question I did not find any way to do the validation.
The validation is done automatically by GeneXus Flexible Client.

Comment: Thank you. Under Localization, I can't find the terms "Preferences", "Server URL" and "User Information" for translation.

Comment: In this case, the Service URL is supposed to be set only once. However, in Android, GX creates this menu, always available throughout the entire application: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2edw40x.jpg - is there any way to hide it?

Comment: I edited my response with some images of the messages I was mentioning. Hope that helps!
There is no way to hide the Preference menu for Android.